British War Office/ Military Intelligence Secret Code Use in the North Russian Allied Intervention 1919-1920
Can anyone describe how secret codes may have been used and shared between British agents during the Russian revolution? Where would the codes have originated? How often would the code need to be updated and why? Would it have been a different process from other periods and geographic locations?

From 1919 it was the responsibility of the newly formed Government Code and Cypher School (GC&CS - later GCHQ) "to advise as to the security of codes and cyphers used by all Government departments and to assist in their provision". More detail is given in Behind the Engima - the authorised history of GCHQ Britain's secret cyber-intelligence agency. Reading chapter 3 (Whitehall's Black Chamber: British Cryptology and the Government Code & Cypher School, 1919-39) in the section titled "Defence", we see that that form its foundation in 1919 up until 1922, the upgrading of British codebooks was a significant task for the new organisation. Ferris writes:-

In 1919, intelligence authorities, the Foreign Office and the military services concluded that during the late war their codes had been 'almost childish', as were their practices, such as sending identical messages in different systems. [...] Under Travis, Britain's leading expert in signals security and cryptosystems, GC&CS was ordered to solve these problems by advising on cryptographic issues, producing codebooks and training personnel for the civil departments.


Travis had no power over the great weakness in British cryptology, the insecurity of the Foreign Office's Communications Department and in its establishments abroad, which let Italy, Japan and the USSR secretly copy British codebooks. He had no control over military practices, though much influence. [...] By 1922, he led departments to superencipher their codebooks and to monitor their use. His section closely watched departmental practices and trained personnel. Each codebook received a 'life history', including every message they covered, to ease damage assessment in case of compromise. Codebooks were compiled by discussions between GC&CS and the relevant department, and printed at Oxford University Press; but GC&CS created the superencipherment tables and produced them on rotoprinters in its first mechanised section.

He goes on to describe the superencipherment tables as using the 'long subtractor' system with keys 10,000 groups long used as a notional 'one-time pad' (in practice re-use was common).
There is therefore evidence of the following answers:

How secret codes may have been used and shared between British agents during the Russian revolution?

Communications were likely superenciphered codebooks shared via the Foreign Office's Communications Department.


Where would the codes have originated?

From consultation between GC&CS and the agent's responsible organisation, with codebooks printed at OUP and tables produced in-house by GC&CS


How often would the code need to be updated and why?

In case of compromise and/or overuse of superencipherment tables. Later in the section Ferris states that "In 1931, GC&CS had the most overexposed departments change tables only once every four months, and thought that under the worst case, any key would remain secure for a month."


Would it have been a different process from other periods and geographic locations?

It was likely one of the early subjects of a major review of British cryptography (Hugh Sinclair was Chief of both SIS and Director of GC&CS and so SIS would have been the department where Travis had most influence). Ferris goes on to remark that by 1944, the consensus (including Travis) of the superencipherment methods was "now we should regard it with contempt".



Ferris cites as two of his sources "Report of Cypher Conference, 27.2.19, ADM 1/8637" and "Foreign Office Circular, 30.1.21, FO 513/1", though I have not seen these documents.
